# Resizing Picture with A tag hover

Tags: html, css

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body
{
 margin:0 auto;
}
.fixed
{
 max-height: 500px;
 max-width: 700px;
}
a:after 
{
 clear: both 
}

a img
{
 height: auto;
 float: left;
 padding: 20px;
 max-height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
a.hovMe
{
 line-height:30px;
 outline: none;
 transition: .125s linear;
}
a.hovMe:hover 
{
 text-decoration:none;
} 
a.hovMe span, a.hovMel span
{
 display:none;
 line-height:16px;
 margin-left:26px;
 margin-top:-30px;
 padding:14px 20px;
 width:500px; 
 z-index:10;
}
a.hovMe:hover span
{ 
 background: white; 
 border:1px solid #000000;
 color:#111;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<a class="hovMe">
   <div style="fixed">
    <img src="http://ito.auburncc.org/localuser/YR16/tmccandless/css/G_pg/img/p1.png" alt="">
    <span>
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat ut lacus in feugiat. Nulla at malesuada nibh. Proin condimentum, augue ac condimentum volutpat, metus justo elementum massa, volutpat tincidunt mi nunc sed libero. Aenean lacinia vehicula ligula, non suscipit diam elementum id. Donec ac leo sem. Donec ac urna nec metus semper tristique. Nunc ac cursus odio, nec bibendum arcu. Vivamus mauris orci, cursus sagittis pulvinar id, congue a quam. Donec laoreet lobortis condimentum. Fusce a diam sit amet ante pharetra rhoncus vehicula vel augue. Donec arcu tortor, iaculis eleifend augue id, molestie blandit ipsum.
    </span>
   </div>
  </a>
```

Ok so I'm trying display some simple text with a `:hover` over a `img` tag inside of an `a` tag. I have it now so it displays text but it doesn't resize the picture and I've tried the `:after` pseudo selector and to no avail.
What i want to happen is what is shown [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-showhide). How this person has when you click the button it will show the text and then resize the image to fit the `block element`. Except with his/hers they have it show the picture and the text first then the picture on top when you press the button, what i want to happen is that there is just  a picture to start then when u hover over it or just click it , it will `transition` into the picture being on top spanning the whole width and then the text being displayed under it.
Also i want it to not move the other picture , basically keep them to always be floated left and each `div` to be self contained. If anyone can help im open for suggestions.
 Thank you !

Comment: At least tell me why its a bad question please.

Comment: Not my downvote, but probably because you didn't include any code in the question. Questions should be self-contained; Fiddles should be supplementary.

Comment: @Utkanos thank you for the advice i will add to what i ment